# Determination of the basis angle in a tilted equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving, angle

I'm trying to solve a geometry problem involving intersecting lines and angles in an equilateral triangle. Could you please explain how to find the measure of the angle marked with a question mark, given that the second marked angle is 71 degrees?

In the sketch, an equilateral triangle is intersected by a pair of parallel lines. Determine the measure of the angle marked with a question mark, given that the second marked angle is 71 degrees.

Here is the sketch:

[sketch1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uywdw.png)

Hope for an answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know angles in the equilateral triangle? Also, do you know the sum of angles in a pentagon?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thank you for wanting to help me but I got it now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here are the steps:-

1. The 60 $^\circ$ comes from the fact that triangle is **equilateral**.
2. The 71 $^\circ$ comes from the **corresponding angle** property of parallel lines.
3. The 109 $^\circ$ comes from **linear pair** of angles.
4. The 169 $^\circ$ comes from the **exterior angle** property of triangle.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow! Thank you! It helped me a lot, I can understand it now. :-)